# Mitsuba Installation Path On Linux Mint

Tags: add-on, linux

**Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela 64-bit MATE 1.10.2**

**Blender 2.76b**

I have no idea where the required Mitsuba installation path actually is?

I've tried using `/usr/share/mitsuba/` but upon rendering with F12, was given a short warning saying "no module named 'numpy'" and a blank render result. As I haven't found anyone else talking about this, I'm pretty sure I am the only person in the world confused by this and I'm sorry for being stumped by what is probably an obvious solution!

[image: Screenshot of the Blender Add-ons tab, depicting the Mitsuba add-on, with a seemingly functioning exporter enabled, but an empty field for the Mitsuba installation path]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the pathway for me was `/usr/bin/`!

But also the `"no module 'numpy'"` warning was part of the problem. While I had *"python-numpy"* installed I didn't have *"python**3**-numpy"* installed. Once I installed it, I could finally render!